# Why does the en_GB locale think the 1st of January is the 52nd week of the year?

Tags: java, locale, date

It turns out that the week-of-year using `ww` as a java date format string is 52 for the 1st January 2011 when the locale is `en_GB`. Here is proof (using a scala REPL, though I could have done this using a Java program)

First get my locales

```
scala> val en = java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales.find(_.toString == "en") getOrElse error("no en")
en: java.util.Locale = en

scala> val en_GB = java.util.Locale.getAvailableLocales.find(_.toString == "en_GB") getOrElse error("no en_GB")
en_GB: java.util.Locale = en_GB
```

Now make the 1st of Jan

```
scala> import java.util.Calendar; import Calendar._
import java.util.Calendar
import Calendar._

scala> Calendar.getInstance
res23: java.util.Calendar = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1300708839128,....]

scala> res23.set(MONTH, JANUARY); res23.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)

scala> val firstJan = res23.getTime
firstJan: java.util.Date = Sat Jan 01 12:00:39 GMT 2011
```

Now declare a method to print this in a locale-dependent way:

```
scala> def weekInLocale(l : java.util.Locale) = { java.util.Locale.setDefault(l); new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("ww").format(firstJan) }
weekInLocale: (l: java.util.Locale)java.lang.String
```

Now invoke it:

```
scala> weekInLocale(en)
res24: java.lang.String = 01

scala> weekInLocale(en_GB)
res26: java.lang.String = 52
```

Is this right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week might be a bit of help, although it doesn't explain why en locale results in week 1. Could timezones have anything to do with this?

Comment: Isn't the case that `en_GB` means UK, while `en` is assumed to be US? And probably UK uses ISO week numbering and US use their own.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, jdk 1.6.0_21.

Comment: @axtavt - interesting, I see the issue on all of 1.6.0_03, 1.6.0_18 and 1.6.0_24

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From ISO8601, week 1 is defined as the week containing January 4th. Since 2011-01-01 was a Saturday, this falls in the previous week.

Since there is no week 0, then 2011-01-01 can also be spelled as 2010-W52-6.

Those wacky Americans, on the other hand, allow for partial weeks. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> The US system has weeks from Sunday
>   through Saturday, and partial weeks at
>   the beginning and the end of the year.

So, they would define it as being the last day of week 1.

Answer (score 3):

for Europe 1 January 2011 W52 is correct.
This is ISO standard for [definition of week 01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)

however various numberings exists for different countries. see [Week_numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering)